# Detach bpf object from event?

Tags: ebpf, bcc-bpf

I want to be able to detach my BPF objects from an attached event. Is the only way to detach from an event to destroy the BPF object?

I'm trying to avoid having to create/destroy objects everytime a new program that I want to trace is launched and/or the events traced are changed.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I haven't tried, but I think this is possible. You can keep loaded eBPF programs on the system by “pinning” them under the virtual BPF file system (`/sys/fs/bpf`), with the `bpf()` system call (or via utilities like bpftool). Then try removing for example a kprobe through the tracefs (see related [kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/kprobetrace.txt)), I think this is how bcc [removes them](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/e8dd701f675af95583caf49fc274f11a099bc473/src/cc/libbpf.c#L1088) too.